# Data preparation before RFECV or any other feature selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, rfe, normalization

I'm trying to figure out if it is wise to remove highly correlated and negatively correlated features before feature selection. Here's a snapshot of my code

```
def find_correlation(data, threshold=0.9, remove_negative=False):
        corr_mat = data.corr()
        if remove_negative:
            corr_mat = np.abs(corr_mat)
        corr_mat.loc[:, :] = np.tril(corr_mat, k=-1)
        already_in = set()
        result = []
        for col in corr_mat:
            perfect_corr = corr_mat[col][corr_mat[col] > threshold].index.tolist()
            if perfect_corr and col not in already_in:
                already_in.update(set(perfect_corr))
                perfect_corr.append(col)
                result.append(perfect_corr)
        select_nested = [f[1:] for f in result]
        select_flat = [i for j in select_nested for i in j]
        return select_flat

corrFeatList = find_correlation(x)
fpd = x.drop(corrFeatList,axis = 1 )

fpd['label'] = catlabel 
fpd = fpd[fpd['label'].notnull()]

Features = np.array(fpd.iloc[:,:-1])
Labels = np.array(fpd.iloc[:,-1])

hpd = fpd.iloc[:,:-1]
headerName = hpd.columns

#Scale first
#Scaling normalisation
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
Features = scaler.fit_transform(Features)

#RFECV logReg first
## Reshape the Label array
Labels = Labels.reshape(Labels.shape[0],)

## Set folds for nested cross validation
nr.seed(988)
feature_folds = ms.KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle = True)

## Define the model
logistic_mod = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C = 10, class_weight = "balanced") 

## Perform feature selection by CV with high variance features only
nr.seed(6677)
selector = fs.RFECV(estimator = logistic_mod, cv = feature_folds)
selector = selector.fit(Features, Labels)

Features = selector.transform(Features)
print('Best features :', headerName[selector.support_])
```

So i've tried it with and without dropping the correlated features and have gotten completely different features. Does RFECV and other features selection (dimensionality reduction methods) take into account these highly correlated features? Am i doing the right thing here? Lastly if removing high threshold features is a good idea should i scale before doing this. Thank you.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

RFECV simply takes your original data, crossvalidates the model and drops the least significant feature with significance provided with your classifier/regressor. 
Then it does the same with all the retaied features recursively. 
So it doesn't explicitly aware of linear correlations.

At the same time high correlations of the features doesn't imply that one of them is the best candidate to remove. Highly correlated feature can bear some usefull data information, for example it can have less variance than the retaiend ones.

Dimensionality reduction doesn't imply removal of highly correlated features in general case, however some linear models like PCA implicitly do this.